# What is the best practice to avoid null pointer /un parsable exception when an array returns a null

Tags: arrays, nullpointerexception, try-catch, numberformatexception

Let's say we have

```
for(Object[] ob:bfTotObj)
{
  double sal1= Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(ob[0]));
  double sal2= Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(ob[1]));
  double sal2= Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(ob[2]));
}
```

If the array returns null, then this usually leads to a null pointer exception or number parsing exception like that.

One way would be to surround every thing in a Try, catch.

other way is to put

```
 for(Object[] ob:bfTotObj)
  {
    if(ob[0]!=null)      
      double sal1= Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(ob[0]));
    if(ob[1]!=null)
      double sal2= Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(ob[1]));
    if(ob[0]!=null)
      double sal2= Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(ob[2]));
}
```

to all the values.

Is there a better way to do this? or what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Post more realistic code.

Answer (score 0):

To be specific to your case this may be a better code

```
for(Object[] ob:bfTotObj)
 {
    double[] sal = new double[ob.length];
    for(int i=0; i < ob.length; i++ )
    { 
       if(ob[i]!=null)      
          double sal[i]= Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(ob[i]));
    }
}   //make sure you put array sal in right place
```

But there are several ways to handle null pointer. basic idea is to avoid NullPointerException, also keeping code clearance. refer [this](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2072719/effective-java-nullpointerexception-handling.html) site to get better understanding.